# How to set path with WP_Filesystem and ftp base / chroot

Tags: theme-development, ftp, filesystem-api

In my theme i will use the WP_Filesystem to write a file to for example:

```
$file = get_template_directory().'/library/assets/css/wpless2css.css';
```

Which outputs something like `/home/user/domain/http_docs/wp-contents/theme/mytheme/library/assets/css/wpless2css.css`

This will work unless the ftp user will be chroot to `/home/user/domain/` (on some servers?).

In the case of a chroot the WP_Filesystem can't find `$file`.

A solution seems to define `FTP_PATH` in wp-config.php into `/home/user/domain/` and use:

```
if(FTP_BASE) $file =  str_replace(FTP_BASE,'',get_template_directory()).'/library/assets/css/wpless2css.css';
```

I'm looking for a solution more robust and support for the different possible permissions systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `FTP_BASE` in my `wp-config` i found the update function of WP broken. Then i realize the update function work the same way and don't need any additional settings.
In `wp-admin/includes/update-core.php` i found the usage of `$wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir()`. This solves my problem too.

On http://xref.wordpress.org/branches/3.8/WordPress/Filesystem/WP_Filesystem_Base.html you will find a list of possible useful functions:

```
string wp_content_dir () 
string wp_lang_dir () 
string wp_plugins_dir () 
string wp_themes_dir ([string $theme = false])
```

In fact @otto give my the answer earlier ([Using wp_filesystem in Plugins](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124900/using-wp-filesystem-in-plugins)), here he wrote:

> When using the $wp_filesystem, there's a handy function call for
>   getting the content directory path: $wp_filesystem->wp_content_dir();.
>   You need to use this function because the "remote" directory path may
>   not be the same as the "local" directory path.